# Query where a Firestore Field is contained in a List

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How would I query a field (String) to see if it matches a string in an array. I know you can query an array with something like this:

```dart
query.where('venue.id', arrayContains: venueId)
// where venue.id is an List and venueId is a string
```

But how would I query if `'venue.id`' is a string and `venueId` is a `List`.

Comment: Please be more specific... Are you asking for flutter or firestore?

Comment: firestore in a flutter app

Comment: Ok so then I’m totally confused.. what and where is venue.id and venueId... I’m sure you try to do very simple thing but your question is very confusing.. any chance to modify your question

Comment: @delmin It does make sense the way they wrote it - it might have been confusing that they said "array" when it is called a `List` in Dart. See my answer if you are still confused :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this using [`Query.whereIn`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/where.html):

```dart
query.where('venue.id', whereIn: ['id1', 'id2'])
```

`whereIn` takes a **list** of values and if the field you are querying matches any of the values, its document is included in the query.

---

[Learn more](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any).

Comment: No.. still confused when I read his question over and over... I knew he wanted to use whereIn clause but I wasn’t sure from the way he asked.. Anyway good job